# How do i continue this if else statement do open a alert() function in the middle of a PHP code?

Tags: php, if-statement, alert

I have a system to apply permit and when they select the permit they like to apply, they will submit the form and the system will check if they have any previous applied permit that is same as the pre requisites.

In gerneral:
If they do not meet the pre requisites, system should pop up a window and tell them 'Sorry, 
you do not have the pre-required permits'.

Else system will check if they have completed a medical questionnaire before. If they do have an existing medical questionnaire, system will store the application details and go to the apply_successful.php page. Else System will take them to medical_questions.php to do the questionnaire.

I tried doing the code out but was stuck at some point of it.

I Tried this so far:

```
<?php
session_start();
include'Connections/database.php';
$conn = dbConnect ();
    if (! $conn)
    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

    $user = $_SESSION['eid'];
    $selectedPermit=$_POST['cat'];
    //print_r($selectedPermit);
    foreach($selectedPermit as $permit)
    {
        $query="SELECT t.PREREQ1, t.PREREQ2, (CASE WHEN (t.PREREQ1 IS NOT NULL) AND (p1.PTYPE IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing1, (CASE WHEN (t.PREREQ2 IS NOT NULL) AND (p2.PTYPE IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing2 FROM type AS t LEFT JOIN permit AS p1 ON (t.PREREQ1=p1.ptype) AND ( p1.EID = '$user' ) AND (p1.STATUS='approved') LEFT JOIN permit AS p2 ON (t.PREREQ2=p2.ptype) AND ( p2.EID = '$user' ) AND (p2.STATUS='approved') WHERE t.PTYPE = '$permit' ";
        $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $missing1=$row['missing1'];
        $missing2=$row['missing2'];

        if($missing1=='1' or $missing2=='1')
        {
            echo '<script>alert("Sorry. You did have not met the Pre-Requisites for '.$permit .'");</script>';
            header ('Location:s_apply2.php');
        }
   }

   foreach($selectedPermit as $permit)
   {
       $query="SELECT PTYPE FROM permit WHERE EID=$user";
       $result=mysql_query($query);

       while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {

          if($row['PTYPE'] == $permit)
          {
              //echo"You have applied for this permit.";
              echo '<script>alert("You have applied for '.$permit .'");</script>';
              header ('Location:s_apply2.php');
          }
       }
   }

  foreach($selectedPermit as $permit)
  {
      $query="SELECT MED FROM emp WHERE EID='$user'";
      $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
      $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      $med=$row['MED'];

      if ($med == 'yes')
      {
          $query = "INSERT INTO permit (EID, PTYPE) VALUES ('$user','$permit' )";
          header('Location:s_apply_success.php'); 
      }
      else
      {
          header('Location:medical_question.php');
      }
      mysql_query($query);
  }
  dbDisconnect($conn);  


?>
```

I restructured the whole page and make it sond logically right. However i am not sure the way i use to echo the script out is correct.

I wonder if anyone can comment on this code?

Thanks so much...help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if(missing1 =='1' or missing2 =='1')` Did you `define()` missing1 and missing2? You're not going to evaluate to true for that due to A. Those not being defined B. Your variables wouldn't be defined even if it was $missing1, etc.. And FORMAAATTTIIIINGGG :(

Comment: @Blake sorry...am i on the right path now?? i am not sure if what i did was right maybe you can let me know all the errors i have then i correct them accordingly? I am really not very good in spotting mistakes maybe u can point it out to me?

Comment: @Blake You were saying that 'You're not going to evaluate to true for that due to A. Those not being defined B.' what is A and B?

Comment: That was merely an ordered list using A and B. Why don't you put in some debug echos in your if statement now and see if it does what you expect? `if($missing1 =='1' or $missing2 =='1')
    {
     echo "Goes into my if statement";
        //I am stuck here...I would like to putan alert() here to notify user 'Sorry,you do not have the pre-required permits...and also stay on the same page which is apply2.php
    }`

Comment: @Blake when i click on proceed from the application page, it goes to apply, success...it did not even show me the echo. The code i stated in my question is the processor page for a submit button....how can i find out the problem?

Comment: Comment out your header line until you have debugged it. Echo out any logic evaluations to make sure you are getting what you're expecting. Do basic debugging.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9690/discussion-between-hubert-and-blake)

Comment: @Blake I have error at my foreach() after i try putting the result from the `select PTYPE from permit where EID = $user` into an array with the while loop. Therefore i got this `$permit_arr[]=$row['PTYPE'];` but how do i put `$permit_arr[]` into the foreach() as [] cannot be use for reading

Comment: `foreach($row['PTYPE'] as $permit)` Try that instead.

Comment: @blake when i use `foreach($row['PTYPE'] as $permit)` they have en error which states invalid argument for foreach() but when i use `foreach(array($permit_arr) as $permit)` i get a blank page...but how do i define the missing 1 and missing 2 maybe thats the problem

Comment: `print_r($row)` returns what? It doesn't seem like that is getting set properly to begin with.

Comment: I think i will try to rewrite the whole script since the logic is not there

Comment: Learning how to debug well is your friend. Logic is easy to change, there's no need to start over. Just tell me what `print_r($row)` returns.

Comment: @blake but any idea whats the best way to compare an array of results from database with another array?? For example if the user have 5 permits, I want to see if it there are any similarities between the 2 arrays. Like array(apple,pear,orange,grape) compare with array(apple,grape). and it will give result either boolean or if there is similarities = 1 no similarities = 0.

Comment: @Blake if i put `print_r($row)` after `$permit_arr=$row['PTYPE'];` the result would be Array ( [PTYPE] => CAT 2OR )

Comment: @Blake But answer should depends on the number of entries permit table have right? if i have 3 permit there, the result not suppose to be only CAT 2OR right?

Comment: `$missing1= $row['missing1'];` isn't a valid reference because $row only has PTYPE array key, no "missing1" or "missing2" keys. Your query isn't providing the data response you're expecting.

Comment: I also meant for you to print_r() inside your foreach loop after your giant blackhole of a mysql query. Your question is going far beyond your initial scope. Keep debugging and come back if you hit a wall that is specific enough to help, not "my entire code needs to be re-written, help?"

Comment: @Blake but i tried the query in sql using the database interface, i was successful...hmm...i don't really get it why the query would not return the array result instead it return only 1 result

Comment: @Blake why print_r($row) and print_r($row['PTYPE'] will return slightly different result? as ion the data is correct but the presentation is different

Comment: @Blake I changed the logic and did some changes to it...i debugged till this `if($row['PTYPE'] == $permit)` statement. But that was with echo and print_r();.I wonder if you can spot any errors or any way i can improve it further?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the javascript alert() function? In that case, you should just echo some javascript like this:

```
echo '<script>alert("error");</script>';
```

Though, watch out where you echo it in the HTML, because it won't work on every place of course. The best part is inside the  tag.

Comment: Putting your code there would still never be displayed. His logic will not be evaluated properly.

Comment: how do you add a php variable to the message?